# How do I know which person released mobile app to AppCenter organization

Tags: visual-studio-app-center-distribute

Is there a way to find who released/uploaded Apk/ipa file to the AppCenter organization. I use Fastlane script to upload releases using the AppCenter Key.

However, I couldn't find a way who (user account) is releasing the Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any proper answer from anyone, however, I figured this out in below.

Navigate to YourOrganization >> YourAppName >> App settings >> People

The App uploader will be default get "Manager" role, he released the app to AppCenter.

Comment: Additionally, I have emailed the MS contact, who said that the AppCenter Audit log feature is in consideration.